# JQuery window width not correct in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, window, width

I have created a plugin which i have cut down to the bare bones of a plugin (i.e. no functionality, just the structure) to debug this issue and it still exists. It deals with resizing divs and bases this on the document's width.

The problem is that the documents reported width is reduced by 17px from its actual width and thus doesnt size the divs correctly.

I have put in alerts to find out where the problem occurs: 
Before "ready" function: 1780px (correct width) 
Inside the "ready" function: 1763px 
Inside the Plugin: 1763px 
(all values returned from "document.width" and "$(document).width()" with same results)

This is only happening within Chrome and still remains even with the plugin reduced to effectively nothing.

Any thoughts on why this is happening?

Comment: Might be the size of the scrollbars is subtracted. Some code would help in localizing the problem.

Comment: I have narrowed it to a more specific place.

If i have an alert showing up prior to the ready function, after clicking OK the Divs render correctly. If this Alert is removed, it returns to being 17px short of its actual width.  Are there any other events or something else that happens when the alert is shown?

Comment: I have just removed all the placeholder text that was forcing scrollbars, and the gap has now reduced to a scrollbar-sized space.  I think you are right in that the scrollbar width has been subtracted. Any ideas for a workaround?

Answer (score 3):

taken from [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

> While JavaScript provides the load
>   event for executing code when a page
>   is rendered, this event does not get
>   triggered until all assets such as
>   images have been completely received.
>   In most cases, the script can be run
>   as soon as the DOM hierarchy has been
>   fully constructed. The handler passed
>   to .ready() is guaranteed to be
>   executed after the DOM is ready, so
>   this is usually the best place to
>   attach all other event handlers and
>   run other jQuery code. When using
>   scripts that rely on the value of CSS
>   style properties, it's important to
>   reference external stylesheets or
>   embed style elements before
>   referencing the scripts.
>
> In cases where code relies on loaded
>   assets (for example, if the dimensions
>   of an image are required), the code
>   should be placed in a handler for the
>   load event instead.

you probably should be using

```
$(window).load(function() {});
```

as trigger event

Comment: If you put $(window).width() in the console, it is also wrong. It's not a matter of when it's called, it's a matter of Chrome including the scrollbar as part of the width via CSS but in JS, it uses the window width with the scrollbar subtracted out.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that jQuery(window).width() return a wrong value in Safari and Chrome.

Comment: Webkit actually doesn't follow the W3C standards on defining width. It includes the scrollbar in the window's width despite the spec saying it shouldn't. Boooo!