# Getting element's width in Chrome using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Suppose I have this image:

```
<img src="images/01.jpg" border="0" rel="shadow" />
```

Then with jQuery, I get its width using:

```
$('[rel="shadow"]').width();
```

Firefox and IE report correct dimensions of the image eg 140px while Chrome reports 0. How to solve this problem?

### Note

I don't want to set explicit width for images eg:

```
<img src="images/01.jpg" border="0" rel="shadow" width="140" />
```

So, how to get width in cross-browser way which is not defined in `width` attribute of elements?

Comment: What version of Chrome? Is the script inside a `load` event handler or `$(document).ready`?

Comment: @Crescent Fresh: Chrome version is: **4.0.295.0** and the script is inside **ready.**

Comment: It seems it poses a problem with both Chrome and Safari.

Comment: @Anthony Forloney: any possible solution to this? Is this a bug in those browsers?

Comment: @Crescent Fresh: $(document).ready won't wait for images to load, it waits for the dom loaded fully.

Comment: As of 9months ago, there was no fixed posted on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/887931/jquery-window-width-not-correct-in-chrome

Comment: @loviji: exactly, that's why I asked. The answer is trivial if we know which of `load` or `ready` is being used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$(window).load(
    function() {
        alert($('img').width());
    }
);
```

This will work: [Test case](http://koper.wowpanda.net/image-width.html). Basically it will wait until images load before executing the code (when the ready function fires the document has been fully loaded but images haven't).

Comment: @Andreas Bonini: Perfect, load never popped up in my mind, Thanks :)

Comment: @andreas-bonini Thanks saved my day!

Comment: @Gagan: you're welcome, I'm happy some of my answers from years ago are still useful today :)