# jQuery win.width() incorrect in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, responsive-design

I have a script which amends the margin of an element when the width of the viewport changes.

Everything was working nicely until I realised that Chrome is interpreting the viewport width incorrectly... and the `< 992` condition is infact returning true at a width of `998`.

This doesn't happen when I am viewing the responsive layouts using the inspector... only when I resize the browser window itself.

I saw this answer and apparently Chrome doesn't stick to the W3C standards and includes the scrollbar in the width - [JQuery window width not correct in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887931/jquery-window-width-not-correct-in-chrome)

Does that mean there's no way around it?

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    var win = $(this); //this = window

    if (win.width() < 576) {
        var widthResize = win.width() * .6;
        $('.header .intro .content').css('margin-top', widthResize);
    }
    else if (win.width() < 768) {
        var widthResize = win.width() * .375;
        $('.header .intro .content').css('margin-top', widthResize);
    }
    else if (win.width() < 992) {
        var widthResize = win.width() * .35;
        $('.header .intro .content').css('margin-top', widthResize);
    }
    else {
        var widthResize = win.width() * .35;
        $('.header .intro .content').removeAttr('style');
    }
});
```

Comment: Why don't you use CSS for this? `margin-top: calc(100vw *.35)`  should do the trick (for the last else)

Comment: @cloned thanks but I imagine the js would still interfere with it? Im thinking its probably best to try and detect which stylesheets are in use instead (if possible)

Comment: You don't need the JS at all (if I'm not mistaken) you put every one of your if/else in a media query with a different `calc()`. CSS is for styling, JS for functional logic/ behavior.